# Arduino - Calculating Resistor's Power and Resistance

Tags: arduino

#### My Question

I know, for example, that using a LED in Arduino without a resistor would cause damages to the Arduino's I/O (damages the LED too?), right? Resistors as far as I know have the two main properties resistance and power, so if I needed to calculate the correct resistor, what would be the steps?

Why for pushbuttons, for example, I don't need it? Is it because it has an internal resistance and LED has an almost zero resistance?

#### My Guess

Let's test if I am getting this right, let's say all I want is to turn on a LED so Arduino's voltage is 5V (controlled by the board) and its ideal current is ~20mA (it has to be controlled by me). For turning on the led without causing damage I would do:

$$I = \frac{V}{R} \rightarrow 20mA = \frac{5}{R} \rightarrow R = 250 \Omega$$

But I also have to know the if power is correct then I do:

$$P = I *V \rightarrow P = 20*10^{-3}*5 \rightarrow P = \frac{1}{10}W$$

So the power that would be applied to the resistor is 1/10W and a 1/8W resistor would be enough since 1/8W is the maximum power that can be applied and it is bigger than 1/10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation would be correct if you had no LED in the circuit.

But a simplified schematic might look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ58uL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice here that it shows you could drive the LED from VCC or to GND. When driven to GND you are sourcing current from the Arduino Pin and when driven from VCC you are sinking current through the Arduino Pin.

Here's handy calculator for the resistor: http://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-led-series-resistor

In this calculator you can set the VF for the LED to anything you like (including zero), so you can see the conditions you set in your question.

For the correct answer you will see that if the LED VF was 2.2 V with a 5 V supply, then the resistor would be 140 Ohms for a 20 mA current and not the 250 Ohms you calculated.

The power dissipated by the "R" is W = I^2 * "R"
In this case with 20 mA and 140 Ohms this gives about 0.06 Watt so a 1/10 W resistor would be more than adequate.

So you need to understand what the VF is for the LED you want to use before you can get an accurate answer to the value of "R".

Just to get you to think about the larger problems, it's more complicated when there are multiple I/O pins driving LED's.

If you look at the datasheet for the Atmega328 (you should get used to understanding datasheets) used in the Arduino Uno: http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf

If you look at Section 32 on the DC characteristics of the device, you will see the absolute maximum I/O port current is actually 40 mA. But there are further restrictions in the Notes. It turns out that within a group of I/O pins the absolute maximum current spread across a group of I/O pins is 100 mA.  See Table 32-2(Notes #3 and #4), these restrictions are in place because of the current density limits for conductors within the integrated circuit. This means that if you were to connect up 5 or more LEDs to a group of I/O pins you could easily exceed the recommendations even at only 20 mA per LED.

So the answers become more complex as you use more I/O to drive load currents, and you could easily increase the risk of damage to the processor if you didn't take these restrictions into account. This is why you see external LED drivers used in situations where even higher pulse currents (PWM brightness control) are used.

Comment: Awesome answer! But, is the power calculantion correct? Do I use the total voltage  (5V) or the one which VF is subtracted?

Comment: Fixed formula inline.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the forward voltage drop of the LED in your calculation. You have to subtract it from your 5V output voltage to have the correct voltage on your resistor. The power is calculated with

$$P=I^2 \cdot R$$